# how can we pass parameter to custom express-validator?

Tags: node.js, express-validator

I would like to prevent a registration with an email address which already exists. Is it possible to use express-validator's new syntax for this? For example:

```
  router.post('/register', [
    check('email').custom((value, {req}) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           Users.findOne({email:req.body.email}, function(err, user){
           if(err) {
             reject(new Error('Server Error'))
           }
           if(Boolean(user)) {
             reject(new Error('E-mail already in use'))
           }
           resolve(true)
         });
    });
  })
]
....
```

How would i pass Users?

Comment: I presume that the `Users` is a mongoose schema. There's no point of passing a mongoose schema to express-validator - I believe you would rather wish to pass the request body fields for the same. And no, express-validator is not the same as fetching the value from the database and checking if the user exists - it can merely check for constraints on the data fields IN the request body and not against their actual values stored in the database..

Comment: Nobody said anything about database, Users could be a list of objects for example. I think i'll have to go with 'check' inside the actual post request function right?

Comment: As I said, I 'presumed' from the code you shared, given the context of express. But yes, you guessed it right - you would have to write the method yourself. An `express-validator` ( or rather any validator ) would not do the task of cherry picking if the item exists in your list of items, neither should it interact with the list of items.  A validator is simply supposed to validate the fields of request entities against the given criteria of data type / length / pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

express-validator is only aware of the request object itself, what keeps its complexity pretty low for the end-user.
More importantly, it only truly knows about the request's input locations -- `body`, `cookies`, `headers`, `query` and `params`.

Your custom validator is completely correct. That being said, it *might not be testable*, as you seem to be depending on global context.

In order to make it testable, the 2 options that I see are:

#### 1. Inject `req.Users`:

This one would involve using some middleware that sets your store objects onto `req`:

```
// Validator definition
const emailValidator = (value, { req }) => {
  return req.Users.findOne({ email: value }).then(...);
}

// In production code
// Sets req.Users, req.ToDo, req.YourOtherBusinessNeed
app.use(myObjectsStore.middleware);
app.post('/users', check('email').custom(emailValidator));

// In tests
req = { Users: MockedUsersObject };
expect(emailValidator('foo@bar.com', { req })).rejects.toThrow('email exists');
```

#### 2. Write a factory function that returns an instance of your validator:

This is my preferred solution, as it doesn't involve using the request object anymore.

```
// Validator definition
const createEmailValidator = Users => value => {
  return Users.findOne({ email: value }).then(...);
};

// In production code
app.post('/users', [
  check('email').custom(createEmailValidator(myObjectsStore.Users)),
]);

// Or in tests
expect(createEmailValidator(MockedUsersObject)('foo@bar.com')).rejects.toThrow('email exists');
```

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comments into a final, conclusive answer here :

A validator is simply supposed to validate the fields of request entities against the given criteria of data type / length / pattern.

You would need to write the method yourself, to determine if the user pre-exists or not. An express-validator ( or rather any validator ) would not do the task of cherry picking if the item exists in your list of items ( or your data-source), neither should it interact with the data-source concerned.